# How to get rid of noisy data in a sequence of real number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say we have a finite sequence $s_1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,100,9,10)$, it is easy to observe that the $100$ is noise data, presuming that the data progressing should have been "smooth" and noise doesn't happen a lot. And likewise for sequence $s_2=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,9)$, the second $2$ could be noise. Now I am looking for mathematical tools or algorithm to detect the noisy data and correct it, without changing others, to more reasonable value, to restore the "smoothness".

I tried simple algorithm: comparing neighboring data from head to tail consecutively, identifying the noisy if the difference is "intolerable", and correct it with the average of its $n$ predecessors. This approach doesn't consider the "big picture" of the sequence so it is hard to generally tell what difference should tolerable. For example, in $s_1$, difference bigger than $2$ might be detected to be noisy, while in $s_3=(1,2,4,6,8,10)$ that might just be OK. Things get trickier when noisy happen to be in the head.

So any help? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each point, do a linear fit to some of the surrounding points and reject the point if it is too far from the fit.

If you have an idea of what the data should look like, for example a power-law, use that when doing the fit instead of the linear fit.

Comment: What if the sequence is the sequence of all primes? Or, the sequence of all codings for the universal turing-machine of turing machines that will halt for some input? Depending on the intention of the question, the answer can be arbitrarily difficult.

Comment: The OP wrote "presuming that the data progressing should have been "smooth" and noise doesn't happen a lot". I was suggesting a  method. My answer was arbitrarily easy.

Comment: I didn't say your answer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Marty is right -- since definition of "smooth" is in the eye of the beholder, so to speak, then the OP himself must decide what fit to use. In case of actual implementation I would also advise to use something like a "qualification window" -- that is, to choose the half-length $h$ of the approximation segment. For instance, set $h=10$ and then for every number $a_k$ run the best fit check for $[k-h;k+h]$ segment with $a_k$ itself excluded. Choice of $h$ will also have to based on the type of data or on some idea of what "behavior" the sequence is supposed to follow.